# Wordpress - Wishlist Member: redirect upon login

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

I currently have a site running on Wordpress with the Wishlist Member plugin installed to control the membership functions of the site. Currently, non-members are redirected to a page with the slug 'sign-up' if they try to access a page requiring membership, with registered users being able to log in on any page via a login form in the header and being directed to a page with the slug 'member-dashboard'.

What I am looking to achieve (which the plugin doesn't afford me the facility to do) is for users logging in to be allowed the opportunity to return directly to the page they were viewing prior to login (this would be via a link on the page 'member-dashboard'). However, I need to be able to take into account if they have been referred by the sign-up page and return them effectively 2 pages back. I also need to take into account if they have failed to login correctly.

I have had a look at some solutions by doing a web search, but none of these are quite doing the trick. Here is what I have thus far (please be kind - I know this is rubbish)

```
<?php if (strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"www.mydomain.co.uk/sign-up/" ) && is_page(9)) { ?>
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-2);">Go back 2 pages as referred by 'sign-up'</a>
<? } elseif (is_page(9)) { ?>
<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo "<a href='$url'>Go back 1 page as referred by another page</a>"; 
?>
<? } ?>
```

I am well aware that this is nonsense, and that I should not be using either the Java solution (this doesn't retain the fact that the user has logged in when serving the page 2 pages back) or HTTP_REFERER (and that the PHP needs a tidy also), but it should demonstrate what it is that I am after achieving at least. This code is in Wordpress' page.php as the code for the plugin is encrypted and I cannot work with this as a result.

I'm guessing that I should be setting up some kind of session variables in order to best accomplish what I need to do in this instance, but I've got to be honest - I haven't managed to unearth anything that seems to help me in this regard. Would anybody be able to at least point me in the right direction? It would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Wow, there's a huge wall of text there. Did you see that? Isn't there any way you can compress it to, say, two paragraphs and a piece of code?

Comment: @Dennis Didn't mean to hurt your eyes dude. Just trying to give as much info as possible. I'm new here too. Don't flame me. Sad face.

Comment: I didn't intend to flame you. What I was trying to say is to find balance between minimalist and overly verbose. They are both just different manifestations of bad imho. Not saying your question is bad, but I don't have the time to read and comprehend your question.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I was just kidding. I understand what you have said though and will try to keep it in mind in the future :)